# Why can you import UpdateView in "multiple ways"

Tags: django, django-generic-views

Why do both of the following ways of importing UpdateView work?:

- 1. from django.views.generic import UpdateView
- 2. from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView

I was assuming 2. was the correct way, and 1. would not work, but from testing both work.

Comment: `django.views.generic` is the `__init__`, and this simply "reexports" the classes defined in `edit.py`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see here is quite common (at least in *some* Python packages). If you define a `.py` file, that acts as a module. For example the `django.views.generic.edit` module maps on the [`django/views/generic/edit.py` file [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.1.x/django/views/generic/edit.py).

A directory is a Python module as well (due to the `__init__.py` file), but it does not contain any elements by default, hence that would mean that `django.views.generic` would be empty.

If we take a look at the [`django/views/generic/__init__.py` file [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/__init__.py), we see:

> ```
> from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView, TemplateView, View
> # ...
> from django.views.generic.edit import (
>     CreateView, DeleteView, FormView, UpdateView,
> )
> # ...
>
> __all__ = [
>     'View', 'TemplateView', 'RedirectView', 'ArchiveIndexView',
>     'YearArchiveView', 'MonthArchiveView', 'WeekArchiveView', 'DayArchiveView',
>     'TodayArchiveView', 'DateDetailView', 'DetailView', 'FormView',
>     'CreateView', 'UpdateView', 'DeleteView', 'ListView', 'GenericViewError',
> ]
>
> # ...
> ```

This thus imports the `UpdateView` from the `generic.py` file, and *re-exports* the class.

You thus can reference to the class in two ways: through the module defined by the `generic.py` file, or through the re-export of the module of the directory, specified through the `__init__.py` file.

This is typically done to export a *portion* of the items that are defined in the files, export these under a more convenient name, or provide some extra classes at the module level (for example the `__init__.py` file defines the `GenericViewError` error).

This directory-level module thus "groups" interesting views together. For example the `FormMixin` is *not* exported at this level. The `__init__.py` here groups (popular) class-based views together, whereas the mixins, that are typically used to define such generic views, are still specific to a file.